# Filenames not being added to ArrayList from different class

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist, filenames

I have a method ***hexFinder*** in the class ***checksumFinder***. In the hexFinder each file is read and named either a *good* file or a *bad* file. It is then put into one of two ArrayLists, ***listGoodFiles*** or ***listBadfiles***.

Both of these ArrayLists belong to the class ***checksumGUI*** in the ***multiFile*** method. This method calls the *hexFinder* for every file inside a chosen folder. It also outputs a message showing how many *good* and *bad* files were in the folder.

When I add the file name to one of the ArrayLists, nothing is added.

Here's some code from the *checksumFinder* class that might be causing the problem

```
class checksumFinder {

checksumGUI cg = new checksumGUI();

String hexFinder(File currentFile,...){

.... // determine file is good/bad 

if (l1 == l2) {
    cg.listGoodFiles.add(currentFile.getName());
    } else{
      cg.listBadFiles.add(currentFile.getName());
    }
```

Here's the *multiFile* method from the *checksumGUI* class

```
public void multiFile(JFileChooser inFileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    checksumFinder cf = new checksumFinder();
    ArrayList<String> listTypeErrFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File folderFile = inFileName.getSelectedFile();
    File[] listAllFiles = folderFile.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listAllFiles.length; i++) {
        File currentFile = listAllFiles[i];
        if (currentFile.isFile() && currentFile.getName().endsWith(".pcf")) {

            cf.hexFinder(currentFile, null, null, null);
        } else {
            listTypeErrFiles.add(currentFile.getName());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------");
            System.out.println("Incorrect filetype:\n" + currentFile.getName());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------\n");
        }
    }

    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(25, 25);
    ta.setText("Folder contains " + listAllFiles.length + " files\n\n"+ "Folder has " + 
            listGoodFiles.size() + " good files;\n" + listGoodFiles + "\nFolder has " +
            listGoodFiles.size() + " bad files;\n" + listBadFiles +"\nFolder has " + 
            listTypeErrFiles.size() + " file of wrong type;\n" + listTypeErrFiles);

            ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            ta.setLineWrap(true);
            ta.setCaretPosition(0);
            ta.setEditable(false);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            new JScrollPane(ta),"Folder Contents", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

From the way I have made this program there is a lot of movement between the two classes. (I'm sure it could be done better but this is the only way I know how)

EDIT:

I have already looked through similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175286/problems-adding-objects-from-a-different-class-into-an-arraylist-java) but nothing I've found has been useful

EDIT:

The (most recent) code for the *checksumFinder* class can be found [HERE](http://pastebin.com/RrSYaYcj).

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `checksumGUI` instance in checksumFinder instead of accessing the existing instance:

```
cg = new checksumGUI();
```

You should make the existing instance a parameter to the constructor instead:

```
class checksumFinder {
    private final checksumGUI cg;

    checksumFinder(checksumGUI cg) {
        this.cg = cg;
    }

    ...
}
```

And instead of `checksumFinder cf = new checksumFinder();` in `multiFile()`, pass the current instance to `checksumFinder` constructor:

```
checksumFinder cf = new checksumFinder(this);
```

(Also, using the java coding conventions, e.g. capitalized class names, would make the code easier to read).